# How to bind each "the_content" elements to a custom variables

Tags: php, functions, filters, the-content, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing bootstrap theme into wordpress and i need you'r help. In Wordpress i created a simple page with paragraph and a list of 3 item's.

Product list one

- Product one - 
  Link
- Product two - 
  Link
- Product three - 
  Link

with a help of bootstrap i'm trying to integrate **accordion** ([collapsible content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/)) into that Wordpress page. But i can't understand how to bind each element from `the_content();` into specific `div`. I think i need to use apply_filters with foreach to create a new div's for each paragraph's/list's ?

Example what im trying to achieve - https://jsfiddle.net/ufr49jg2/

Comment: probably should look at creating a shortcode for this that you can pass the product IDs to and use it to output the desired markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As majick suggested on a comment you could use a shortcode to create the accordion markup.

If you want to manually define the tab titles and content, you could add something like this to your functions.php.

```
add_shortcode( 'accordion', 'accordion_callback' );
function accordion_callback( $args, $content ) {

  $defaults = array(
    'id' => 'exampleAccordion'
  );
  $args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $args, 'accordion' );

  return sprintf(
    '<div id="%s" class="accordion">%s</div>',
    $args['id'],
    do_shortcode($content)
  );  
}

add_shortcode( 'accordion_tab', 'accordion_tab_callback' );
function accordion_tab_callback( $args, $content ) {

  $defaults = array(
    'title' => 'Default tab title',
  );
  $args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $args, 'accordion_tab' );

  $tab_heading = '<div class="card-header">' . $args['title'] . '</div>';
  $tab_content = '<div class="collapse">' . $content . '</div>';

  return '<div class="card">' . $tab_heading . $tab_content . '</div>';
}
```

You'd then use these like this in your post content,

```
[accordion id="my-accordion"]
[accordtion_tab title="Tab 1"]Tab 1 content[/accordtion_tab]
[accordtion_tab title="Tab 2"]Tab 2 content[/accordtion_tab]
[/accordion]
```

Or if your tab content consists of separate posts, you could pass the post ID's as the shortocde parameter and build the accordion markup based on the found post data. For example,

```
add_shortcode( 'accordion_products', 'accordion_products_callback' );
function accordion_products_callback( $args ) {

  $defaults = array(
    'products' => ''
  );
  $args = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $args, 'accordion_products' );

  $products = explode( ',', $args['products'] );
  $products = array_map('absint',$products);

  $accordion = '';
  foreach ( $products as $product_id ) {
    // get product data, e.g get_post(), or wc_get_product() if working with WooCommerce
    // create tab html
    // concat html to $accordion
  }

  return $accordion; 
}
```

Then use the shortcode like this,

```
[accordion_products products="1,2,3,4,5"]
```

A variation of this option is to group the posts with (custom) taxonomy terms, where each term represents one accordion. Then pass the ID of one of the terms as a shortcode parameter and query posts based on the term id.

**N.B.** The examples above are simplified and you should only use them as a starting point and modify them to match your exact needs. But feel free to post new questions to WPSE, if you encounter any problems while developing the solution.